# c# opening of a form

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I prevent multiple form opens

```
FormTanımlama frmTanimlama = new FormTanımlama();
FormRapor frmRapor = new FormRapor();

frmTanimlama.Close();
frmRapor.Close();

FormIslem frmIslem = new FormIslem();
frmIslem.MdiParent = this;
frmIslem.Show();
```

Other forms doesn't close When I open a new form

Comment: It is very unclear what you mean. In particular, it is your code that *opens* the form; so what code are you using and what isn't bahaving as you like? Also: is this winforms? wpf? etc?

Comment: Do you mean multiple instances of the same program runnning? Like how you can only open just one WinZip at a time (default option)?

Comment: What forms are you talking about? You need to provide more details if you expect any viable answers.

Comment: The thing about programming is, you have to tell the computer exactly what to do.  If you want other windows to close, you have to close them explicitly.

Comment: i thing you should rewrite your question.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to need to give more details to get a more detailed answer.

But the simple answer is, your program should have an understanding of how your program functions. You will need to make some form of flag or structure that keeps track of what you have open so you can decide if other forms can be opened. You should be doing this check before the `new Form()` call so that you don't do all the initialization steps of the form when you are going to just reject it and not retain a reference to it.

Comment: FormTanımlama frmTanimlama = new FormTanımlama();
            FormRapor frmRapor = new FormRapor();
            frmTanimlama.Close();
            frmRapor.Close();
            FormIslem frmIslem = new FormIslem();
            frmIslem.MdiParent = this;
            frmIslem.Show();
other forms doesn't close
When I open a new form

Comment: Edit your question and use code formatting if you are going to add more details. Also, that code only ever shows one form and calls close on the others without them ever being shown.

Comment: +1 for "your program should have an understanding of how your program functions"